# Web API with Entity Framework inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

Suppose I have the following entities:

```
abstract class User
{
    string Id 
    string Name 
}

class UserA : User
{
    List<UserB> Bs
}

class UserB : User
{
    string UserAId
    [ForeignKey("UserAId"), JsonIgnore]
    UserA UserA
}
```

I want to load all of them in one query and get only the id of the collection. For example, if return

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Usuario> Get()
{
   return _context.Users.ToList();
}
```

The response include all data from "Bs" collection

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "User A",
        "Bs": [
            {
                "id": "1",   
                "name" : ....  
                "aId": ....
            },
            {
                "id": "2",      
                "name" : .... 
                "aId": ....
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "aId": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "User B 1"
    },
    {
        "aId": "0",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "User B 2"
    }
]
```

How to get the collection without the extra properties?

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "User A",
        "Bs": [
            {
                "id": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "aId": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "User B 1"
    },
    {
        "aId": "0",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "User B 2"
    }
]
```

And return this json without "aId" and "name" from the "Bs" collection

Answer (score 0):

To return the ids from the type UserA's Bs collection, you need to filter out the values based on the type and then use SelectMany on the Bs collection

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<int> Get()
{
   return _context.Where(e => (e is UserA))
                  .Select(u => (UserA)u)
                  .SelectMany(b => b.Bs)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I want only the ids from "Bs" collection

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I have two problems
- i can't SelectMany(u => u.Bs) from users collection because Bs is only a property from UserA
- I need the result to be of type IEnumerable<User>, I updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a select statement to project the id like:

```
_context.Users.Select(user => user.id)
```

You will have to change the return type

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-syntax-examples-projection

Comment: I want only the ids from "Bs" collection

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with this method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> res = _context.Users.OfType<UserA>()
        .Select(u => new {Id = u.Id, Name = u.Name, Users =  u.Users.Select(ui => new  { Id = ui.Id }) })
        .ToArray();

    res = res.Concat<dynamic>(_context.Users.OfType<UserB>());

    return res;
}
```